# Same SFTP remote host for all projects in WebStorm & PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have one dev server to which I publish all my projects via SFTP. I find it quite complicated so far to create a new remote host setting for each project as each actually shares the same host.

What is a straight forward way to use one remote host and get many projects under that hood? It doesn't make sense for me to create one giant project with all subprojects. It would take loads of redundant resources.

Comment: Deployment entry can be visible to current project .. and all projects (IDE-wide entry). For IDE-wide one login details will remain the same (enter only once) but path mappings/exclusions need to be provided separately in each project. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deployment-connection-tab.html

Comment: @LazyOne so are mapping and exclusions always saved project specific although a sftp login can be IDE wide? If I set a mapping for one project I won't have it set in another project?

Comment: Yes, mappings are always project-specific. You can create new deployment entry, make it IDE wide and configure it in one project (and test it of course). Then open another project and see if that entry be there and what fields you need to fill. P.S. Before (4-5 years ago or so) all deployment entries were IDE-wide.